# Сравнить колонки ИНН в двух листах и копировать сумму

Tags: excel, vba

Два листа *Excel* -  в одном листе есть колонка *ИНН* (и еще много других не важных), во втором листе тоже *ИНН* и еще одна колонка *сумма*/

Нужно с помощью макроса сравнить колонки *ИНН* в двух листах и скопировать сумму совпавшего *ИНН* в первый лист. Нумерация строк на листах не соблюдается, *ИНН* расположены хаотчно.

Написал код, но он останавливается на первом совпадении.

Пример excel не знаю как добавить здесь

Ппомогите пожалуйста

```
Sub INN()
iLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row      'последняя строка на листе1
For i = 2 To iLastRow   'последняя строка на листе1
For i = 2 To iLastRow   'последняя строка на листе1
If Worksheets(2).Range("C" & i).Value = Worksheets(1).Range("J" & i).Value Then
    Worksheets(2).Range("K" & i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(1).Range("E" & i)
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: *скопировать сумму совпавшего ИНН в первый лист* Требуемое действие выполняет функция `ВПР()`.

Answer (score 1):

В первом листе ИНН в столбце *J*, столбец для сумм - *E*

Во втором листе ИНН в столбце *C*, столбец с суммами - *K*

На двух листах в первых строках шапки таблиц.

Работаем с массивами (с объектами листа очень медленно)

```
Sub INN_Sum()
Dim aINN(), aData(), aSum()
Dim lRwINN, lRwData
Dim i As Long, k As Long
    With Worksheets(1)
        lRwINN = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row ' по столбцу с ИНН'
        aINN = .Range("J1:J" & lRwINN).Value ' массив ИНН'
        ReDim aSum(1 To lRwINN, 1 To 1) ' размерность массива сумм'
        aSum(1, 1) = .Range("E1").Value ' заголовок столбца суммы'
    End With

    With Worksheets(2)
        lRwData = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row ' по столбцу с ИНН'
        aData = .Range("A1:K" & lRwData).Value ' массив ИНН-сумма'
    End With

    For i = 2 To lRwINN ' проходим по ИНН'
        For k = 2 To lRwData ' проходим в данным'
            If aINN(i, 1) = aData(k, 3) Then ' ИНН совпал'
                aSum(i, 1) = aData(k,11): Exit For ' заносим сумму в массив'
            End If
        Next k
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' обновление экрана отключаем'
    Worksheets(1).Range("E1:E" & lRwINN).Value = aSum ' выгружаем суммы на лист'
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' обновление экрана включаем'

    MsgBox "Готово", 64, ""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно два вложенных цикла делать и переменные в них должны быть разные.
И где вы последнюю строку 2 листа считаете?

```
Sub INN()
iLastRow = Worksheets(1).Cells(Worksheets(1).Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row      'последняя строка на листе1
iLastRow2 = Worksheets(2).Cells(Worksheets(2).Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row      'последняя строка на листе2
For i = 2 To iLastRow   'последняя строка на листе1
  For i2 = 2 To iLastRow2   'последняя строка на листе2
    If Worksheets(2).Range("C" & i2).Value = Worksheets(1).Range("J" & i).Value Then
    Worksheets(2).Range("K" & i2).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(1).Range("E" & i)
    End If
  Next
Next
End Sub
```